# Why does $a\gt 2\pm 2\sqrt{3}\;$ result in $\;a\gt 2+2\sqrt{3}\;$ and $a<2-2\sqrt{3}.\;$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm just curious as to why $a>2\pm2\sqrt{3}$ results in $a>2+2\sqrt{3}$ and $a<2-2\sqrt{3}$.  I'm sure it's a really simple explanation, but intuitively I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The inequality $a < 2 - 2\sqrt{3}$ does not make sense.

Comment: Read, first, about [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems unusual to have an inequality of the form $a>\pm c.$

Comment: I think $a>2\pm2\sqrt{3}$ is ambiguous: is it supposed to mean $a>2+2\sqrt{3}$ and $a>2-2\sqrt{3}$? Or $a>2+2\sqrt{3}$ or $a>2-2\sqrt{3}$? Can you provide more context? I guess this is one step of a bigger problem.

Comment: In the context where I imagine that this appeared, it's a rather serious error to even write “$a > 2 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}$” in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Earlier in your calculations, you had $$(a-2)^2>12$$.  The next step is $$|a-2| > 2\sqrt{3}\\a-2>2\sqrt{3} \text{ or }a-2<-2\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

???  It **doesn't**!  Surely you will agree that $2+ 2\sqrt{3}> 2- 2\sqrt{3}$?  Because for any a and b> 0, $a+ b> a- b$.  If $x> 2\pm 2\sqrt{3}$ then $x> 2+ 2\sqrt{3}> 2- 2\sqrt{3}$.  Perhaps you meant $|x|> 2\pm 2\sqrt{3}$?  Though that still wouldn't give exactly what you have.